# MOXy/JAXB annotations are being ignored on weblogic 12c

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, weblogic, moxy

For some reason weblogic 12c (Eclipse link 2.4.2) seems to be ignoring all my annotations.

For example, classes being marshalled have the following annotation tag but the default accessor type is still being used.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
```

Fields with the following annotation are also not being ignored:

```
@XmlTransient
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.  I have the jaxb.properties file in the correct package along with my marshaller looking similar to the following:

```
final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MappingProfiles.class);
final Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

jaxbMarshaller.marshal(mappingProfiles, baos);
```

Comment: Did you also mark @XmlTransient on any public getters?

Answer (score 0):

This scenario definitely works (As MOXy lead I would have been fired if it didn't).  Is there a chance you are including the JAXB API classes in what you are deploying to WebLogic?